# IP Whitelisted Media Delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, whitelist

I want to set up a cloud services, ideally on AWS, GCP or Azure that will allow me to do media delivery to users on their mobiles phones. The important element is that the media should be accessed by an IP Address I can whitelist with the mobile network providers so that my company can cover the cost of the data transfer over the mobile network.

Any ideas on what Cloud Architecture I would need?

Thanks!

Comment: To be sure to understand: you want to serve media from the cloud and you want this media be accessible from an IP, and not a DNS, right? If so, do you have other constraints? Static or dynamic serving? can scale to 0? special hardaware requirement (GPU,...)? Latency requirement? Global deployment?

Comment: confirmed, it needs to be an IP. Ideally we will be able to scale to a list of known/static IP addresses. no specific hardware requirements at this stage, but would be awesome to serve the content in adaptive bit rate streaming with AES encryption at some point in the future. Latency not that much of a concern. Deployment will primarily be in Africa

Answer (score 1):

On Google Cloud, you can easily get an IP to serve data on internet.

Compute Engine can have a public IP, you can reserve it to be sure to always use the same. However, if you scale up, it's not perfect.

The best, IMO, is to use [Global HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https). You have 1 anycast IP and you can plug the backend that you want on it

- Manage Instance Group (group of VM)
- Cloud Storage bucket, to service static content
- Serverless product like Cloud Run, Cloud Function and App Engine.

In addition, you can cache your content on CDN and have a WAF protection with Cloud Armor.